# How to make onscreen keyboard automatically pop up when entering input field

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and an offical Raspberry Pi touchscreen and I want to use them as a tablet. This sort of works by installing an onscreen keyboard, but the keyboard does not automatically pop up when entering an input field like on for instance Android. Is there a way to make this work?

I am willing to change OS from Raspberian to something else or make some code changes if that is what it takes.

Comment: Have you tried running Android on the Pi? The modifications required for this to work are kind of extreme, and Android already has this in place.

Comment: I haven´t looked into using Android. I wasn´t aware it was an option really. I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: Here's something to get you started: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @pandalion98: Are there any versions of Android for the Pi that are truly usable? Last I saw most distributions struggled to even boot properly.

Comment: @Jacobm001 There are versions that are usable, more or less. https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 5):

Florence virtual keyboard [claims](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/usage.html#modes) to have this feature (called "auto-hide mode"), which should work with modern applications implementing accessibility API (e.g. [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B#History) and [Qt 5](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/06/18/qt-5-accessibility-apis/)):
[image]

For a system-wide experience, you'll probably have to install a modern desktop environment like GNOME or KDE. As far as I know, default Raspbian desktop lacks such features.